# How to normalize the given bounding box coordinates and also normalize them for resized images?

Tags: deep-learning, yolo

I have a dataset that provides bounding box coordinates in the following format.

height- 84 width- 81  x - 343 y - 510. Now, I want to normalize these values (0-1) to train them using the yolov5 model. I have looked online and found that I can normalize these values in 2 ways. Way 1:

```
   Normalized(Xmin) = (Xmin+w/2)/Image_Width
   Normalized(Ymin) = (Ymin+h/2)/Image_Height
   Normalized(w) = w/Image_Width
   Normalized(h) = h/Image_Height
```

Way 2:   divide x_center and width by image width, and y_center and height by image height.
Now, I am not sure which way I should follow to normalize the values in the given dataset. Can anyone suggest me any solution? Also, the size of the given images in my dataset is 1024 x 1024. Now, if I convert the images in 512 x 512 size, how do I figure the new bounding box coordinates i.e what will be the value of height widht x and y?

Answer (score 1):

First, Yolov5 will resize your images and bounding boxes for you, so you don't have to worry about that. By default, it will resize the longest side to 640px and the shortest side will be resized to a length that preserves the aspect ratio of the original image.

About the normalization [0-1]. `Yolov5` expects the center points of the bbox, not the minimum points, so if your **box dimensions** are`height = 84px` and `width = 81px` and **those `x` and `y` are the minimum points of the bbox** (i'm not sure from your post), your formula works, because you're  computing the center points:

```
Normalized(**x_center**) = (Xmin+w/2)/Image_Width
Normalized(**y_center**) = (Ymin+h/2)/Image_Height
...
```

About the resizing:
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/discussions/7126#discussioncomment-2429260